# iOS: Create UIScrollView with dynamic contentSize in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

For my project I need to use a `UIScrollView` which scrolls vertically through the screen's content. The screen's content can grow offscreen since there is a label that has a dynamic size.

I did the following in Interface Builder:

```
-View
--UIScrollView (constraint to superview "View": 0,0,0,0) 
---UIView/contentview (constraint to superview "UIScrollView": 0,0,0,0) + equals width to root view "View" 
----subview .. 
----subview .. etc 
----Label("Some huge dynamic text")
```

The label has constraints to the container view top, leading, trailing and bottom edges.

However, when I run the application, it won't dynamically set the contentSize for the UIScrollView. 
I don't want to use the tricks from other Stack Overflow posts where a runtime variable is created, or where the view is made bigger offscreen.

*How do you tell interface builder without code, that the UIScrollView should grow dynamically depending on the content and scroll only vertically?*

Comment: Are you sure your label size is correctly stretched? Like `sizeToFit`

Comment: Yes, the label is in the exact centre of the container view with sizeToFit on the Label (cmd + =) However the label is not visible and the scrollview is not scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following did the trick:

*"Basically, in order for this too work all the views you put inside of the container view must have a height. Some views will use their intrinsic content height, which will be determined by the width typically. As a general rule, you’ll need to specify a height and width for any view that does not contain text. Those views that do contain text should at least have a specified width or margins."*

[This](http://nscookbook.com/2015/06/ios-programming-recipe-36-a-fixed-width-dynamic-height-scrollview-in-autolayout/) tutorial should help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `label.sizeToFit()` and `scrollView.layoutSubviews()`.

If this isn't working try to add a height constraint to your label and manually set its constant to the size you need :

```
let expectedSize = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.max))
labelHeightConstraint.constant = expectedSize.height
self.view.layoutSubviews()
```

In the controller's `updateViewConstraints()`.

Comment: I tried calling label.sizeToFit() and scrollView.layoutSubviews() in the updateViewConstraints(), however that wont give any different results.